# rails 3 problems with routes on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following routes:

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :kids do
    get   '/sons_report/'                         => 'kids#sons_report',            :as => :sons_report
    get   '/courses/'                             => 'courses#index',               :as => :courses
    post  '/courses/:id'                          => 'courses#show',                :as => :course
    get   '/courses/:id/edit'                     => 'courses#edit',                :as => :edit_course
    put   'courses/:id/update'                    => 'courses#update'
  end
end
```

on my edit view I have the following form:

```
= form_tag dashboard_kid_edit_course(@course), :method => 'post', :multipart => true do
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      %h1.box-title
        %i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-fw
        Schedule
    .panel-body
      = _('Add a new slot')
      %hr{style: "margin-top:0px;"}
      %table.table.table-bordered
        %thead
          %tr{style: "background-color:#4b3087;color:#fff;text-align:center;"}
            %th Hours
            %th Monday
            %th Tuesday
            %th Wednesday
            %th Thursday
            %th Friday
            %th Saturday
            %th Sunday
        %tbody
          %tr
            %td
              %span.badge.badge-success 8 - 10
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'monday_8-10', 'true', false
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'tuesday_8-10', 'true', false
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'wednesday_8-10', 'true', false
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'thursday_8-10', 'true', false
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'friday_8-10', 'true', false
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'saturday_8-10', 'true', false
            %td
              = check_box_tag 'sunday_8-10', 'true', false
        ...
```

But I getting the following error when I try to edit the course:

> undefined method `dashboard_kid_edit_course' for
>
> ## <#:0xa8701d0>

I know that I have a problem with the action of my form but I can find it, any help please.

Thanks

Comment: Does this work? `form_tag edit_course_path(@course), ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `rake routes`. There you can see that the URL prefix is `dashboard_kid_edit_course`. Also you can see that it requires `:kid_id` and `:id` (of the course). I'd imagine you have a `@kid` instance available, so the correct call to the helper should look like this:

```
dashboard_kid_edit_course_path(@kid, @course)
```